# Why I have to wait some seconds before I can input my password on login?

Tags: login-screen, gdm, login, password

When on login I click on the user, immediately shows password field but before I can type it I have to wait some seconds, sometimes even 5! I don't see this problem on other computers that I have, only one has this behavior. Anyone has this problem too? How can I check which components slowdown login time?

Comment: Login Screen is Administration, btw that option is not ticked and it's available only if I choose automatic login, that's not my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It could just be your processor(s) warming up, same with the video card. I sometimes have a similar problem, however, you can still type while it doesn't show the password being entered, you can even press enter. It'll still take a few seconds for the computer to realize that you've told it to login.

Out of curiosity, is this only after shutdown, or sleep and hibernation too?

Comment: Yeah I used to have this too. It went away when I install Lucid. Have you tried disabling Compiz? I'm not sure but maybe that helps.

Comment: Me? I've had some really funky stuff going on, compiz doesn't start until after I login (I had to add it to my startup list manually for some reason)

Comment: Only after shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be a very low video performance (there are some video effects from writing the user name to writing the password). Is your video performance good ?

Comment: Yeah, defintely. Now my login is quick, maybe in two days it will be randomly slow again. This is my trouble.

Answer (score 0):

My computer does the same thing.  It's probably just finishing some things in the background so that it can show you a login screen more quickly.  Some initial keyboard lag is usually likely when resuming from hibernation or starting up for the first time.